# Extending Doctrine entity in another Symfony bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entities, extending

I have three bundles:

- MainBundle - holds entities and all generic functionality
- BundleA & BundleB which will extend Entities in MainBundle and each will also implement interface in that bundle.

With this solution i want to keep MainBundle unaware on other bundles and only have default functionality that Entity should have in it. And other two bundles are aware of MainBundle (but unaware of each other) and have some extend functionality.

Example entity in MainBundle:

```
<?php
namespace Random\MainBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Person
{
  protected $id;

  protected $first_name;

  protected $last_name;

  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function getFirstName()
  {
    return $this->first_name;;
  }

  public function getLastName()
  {
    return $this->last_name;;
  }
}
```

Example class in BundleA extending Entity in MainBundle:

```
<?php
namespace Random\BundleA\Model;
use Random\MainBundle\Entity\Person as BasePerson;
use Random\BundleA\Model\PersonInterface;

class Person extends BasePerson implements PersonInterface
{
  public function foo()
  {
    $data = array(
        'object_id' = $this->getId(),
        'name' = $this->getFirstName(),
        'extra' = 'foo'
    );
    return json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

Example class in BundleB extending Entity in MainBundle:

```
<?php
namespace Random\BundleB\Model;
use Random\MainBundle\Entity\Person as BasePerson;
use Random\BundleB\Model\PersonInterface;

class Person extends BasePerson implements PersonInterface
{
  public function bar()
  {
    $data = array(
        'person_id' = $this->getId(),
        'last_name' = $this->getLastName(),
        'random' = 'bar'
    );
    return $data;
  }
}
```

The problem with this setup is that Symfony/Doctrine expects Random\MainBundle\Entity\Person to be "mapped superclass" which i want it not to be.

EDIT:

In Doctrine1 i was able to extend any Doctrine_Record without having to define simple, concrete or column aggregation inheritance:

```
<?php
class Person extends BasePerson
{
  // some functionality
}

class TestPerson extends Person
{
  // additional functionality
}
```

And in controller i was able to simply:

```
<?php
$person = new TestPerson();
$person->save();
```

and TestPerson (which was actually Person) was saved into database (which i was later able to access using PersonTable).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you going to use MainBundle's class Person directly? Or you will only use child classes in BundleA and BundleB?

Comment: Ideally i would like to have both options but i started to think that maybe it is more reasonable to always use it indirectly (to always use child classes) - for concistency.

Comment: If you will not use MainBundle's class Person directly, then make it a mapped superclass.

Comment: However, if you do need all entities, you can do it using "Class Table Inheritance". Look here for more - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Comment: As i understand i am unable to do anything similar without setting up any kind of inheritance? Unlike in Doctrine1 where i was able to extend any Doctrine record without any extra work if i wanted?

Comment: you can create PersonAbstract under MainBundle and make it mapped superclass.
than create Person extending PersonAbstract in MainBundle, BundleA, BundleB